# Ember.js controller variables reseting after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, routes, page-refresh

Using Ember.js:

I have a Route

```
App.QueryDataRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        propertyObject: this.controllerFor("cres").get("properties").findBy('title', params.propertytype_title),
        nrOfOffers: this.controllerFor("queryData").get("nrOfOffers"),
        deal: this.controllerFor("queryData").get("deal"),
        price: this.controllerFor("queryData").get("price"),
        surface: this.controllerFor("queryData").get("surface"),
    });
  }
});
```

All those .get('*[variable name]*') are variables inside QueryData controller.

Update: added controller

```
App.QueryDataController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  id: null,
  property: null,
  deal: null,
  nrOfOffers: null,
  price: null,
  surface: null,

actions: {
    checkPropType: function (county, property, dealtype) {
        if(property.title ==="Apartment"){
                this.send('populateEstateData', property.title, dealtype.title, county.nrOfApartSale,county.avgPriceApartSale, county.avgSurfaceApartSale);
        }else if(property.title ==="House"){
                this.send('populateEstateData', property.title, dealtype.title, county.nrOfHouseSale,county.avgPriceHouseSale, county.avgSurfaceHouseSale);
        };  
    },

    populateEstateData: function(pProperty, pDeal,pNrOfOffers, pPrice, pSurface){
        this.set('id', 1);
        this.set('property', pProperty);
        this.set('deal', pDeal);
        this.set('nrOfOffers', pNrOfOffers);
        this.set('price', pPrice);
        this.set('surface', pSurface); 
    }},
```

PROBLEM: After page refresh I lose those variables ofcourse because they are declared as **null** again inside the controller.

QUESTION: How can I not reset the variables inside the contorller after page refresh so that I can load them again from Route.

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: Added the controller, thanks!

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Data is hold in your controller then it is returned in model hook to controller again. When do you set those attributes in controller?

Comment: I have edited the controller for simplicity.

Comment: checkPropType is  called by a function in another controller which is itself called by pressing submit button on a Ember.select form. Then those selected will be forwarded to checkPropType as county, property, dealtype.
Those are needed parameter to populate the variables: id, property, nrOfOffers,... in QueryDataController. These variables are now needed in the QueryDataRoute for displaying even after page refresh.
Hope my explanation was not too complicated.

Comment: this is very convoluted approach.  you are using controller to set the model and then using that model to set the controller again.  What you might not realize is that that same ObjectController is _proxying_ the model you are setting in the route.  You essentially have two sets of identical _properties_ that in the worst case conflict and overwrite each other and at best, confuse you as to which ones are actually being manipulated.  I would advise editing your question to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Grapho thanks for the feedback. I am beginner programmer learning javascript using Ember, so no suprise I am doing things a bit difficult for myself. Will go over your idea and try to make it more simple.

Comment: I want to display data (price, surface) on my page and those variables are set in the Controller. In my html I have those variables in handlebars.
{{price}} and {{surface}} inside <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="queryData">. 
All data is lost once page refreshes. How can I avoid losing this data in controller or do I have to fetch the data again in the controller after every page refresh.
If that is the case, ho can avoid Ember.Select losing its selection after page refresh OR get all URL parameters inside the one controller so I can fetch the data based on those parameters again from db?