# Ember CLI -- How can I get variables to survive page refreshes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm setting a variable on my application controller and calling it from other controllers.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  foo: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.foo'),
});
```

This works great for keeping information when re-routing, but the only problem is that it does not survive a manual refresh of the page.  So how do I make it so that it does?  I only found one other question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833032/ember-js-controller-variables-reseting-after-page-refresh) but it does not have an answer.

Comment: In order a computed property get his value you must consume it somehow. So in your initial page load you should using something like {{foo}} in your template or this.get('foo') somewhere else, in order compute foo value.

Comment: There's no problem with it being computed.  The issue is that if the user refreshes the page, all the values that have been computed disappear.

Comment: use browser's `localStorage` or `indexedDb` to store and retrieve the values.

Comment: Makes sense; don't know why I didn't think of that.  If you want to enter this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.